# How do gathering skills work?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

The description of the gathering skills is somewhat unclear. They always read:

> Allows the user to find more resources at certain *gathering* spots.

I initially assumed this just meant I could collect more items, but now I'm wondering if it just means that at certain spots I have a chance to get a wider variety of items, and not just more. Additionally, if they allow you to gather more per spot, is it a one-for-one increase, or does each additional point just give me higher chance to gather additional spots?

Exactly how do gathering skills work?

Comment: I started upgrading the gathering skills on a gathering character and it appears that they give a chance to get more, it's not a 1-1 relation. I'll need to do more testing to confirm. I'm still not sure if the skill has any impact on the items you actually get.

Comment: The way it was in EO IV, similar skills (like Dendrology, Mineralogy and such) added a chance to each gathering that you will find one rare resource in addition to what you got from the gathering. But I'm not sure whether they changed it for EOU. (And I envy you, who knows whether we'll get it in Europe. :-P)